# how to hiding Ubuntu and postgreSQL versions?

Tags: 12.04, postgresql

I'm seeking to closing some vulnerabilities of my postgreSQL server that is running over ubuntu 12.04 server, some of these vulnerabilities is an ability of scanners to checking versions of my OS and DBMS. how can I passing this issue.
Thank you..!!

Comment: Would you mind clarifying a bit at what level you want to block the version query? Are the scanners already on your server or are they accessing your server over the network?

Comment: Not locally, they accessing my server through network.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a Wikipedia article about [Security through Obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) gives you a nice view why just hiding the vulnerable version number **instead of fixing the actual vulnerability** is not a good idea.

**Hiding the PostgreSQL version.** The PostgreSQL protocol does not reveal the actual server version for the connecting clients at connection start-up phrase (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/protocol-flow.html ). Thus, the scanner should be able to connect and authenticate into the PostgreSQL server making it capable to issue SELECT version() SQL query (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-info.html). If a scanner was able to run this command, it needed to authenticate.

- enable authentication;
- block PostgreSQL TCP ports with a firewall

**Hiding the OS version.** This is more complicated process, as multiple server softwares *may* reveal the OS version in their startup protocol. I do not know any server that does it though.

- block unnecessary TCP ports with a firewall